# Sound noise reduction

Tags: noise, audacity, removal

I'm currently working on an engine record and I try to remove an "air" sound with Audacity. I've tried high pass filter and then noise reduction, here the original sample and the edited sample. But I think better is possible, however I don't know how. Do you have some tips on Audacity or Adobe Audition?

**Original sample:** https://mega.nz/#!tNVnSYgR!AgSr3xcqZWC3N_zJKPJCQr3mMzfSYO2G4Cif4YKF2AE

**Edited sample:** https://mega.nz/#!cdUxHICC!0t6_LAtr8rurSbQdwqtdKBXgt0yIwlxpaOqsrtSTHYc

Thanks

Comment: Mark is correct here - re-record. That said, have a play with the current leader in noise reduction: Izotope RX - I can't get it to remove your airflow noise in any major way, but you may have enough success for you to use

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the wrong way. You can't fix this in post and make it a usable recording. When you are recording an engine such as this you need to ensure that you test multiple locations for the microphones and pick the locations that give you the sound you need. The solution is in the recording, not in trying to remove half the spectral range with audacity or audition.

What you have done in the edit is simply to filter out almost half the audible spectrum - problem is that the sound is essentially the same, just with less high-frequencies.

So to recap, get back out there with your microphones and put them in a position away from the airflow component that is giving you the issue - possibly the air filter. Put the mics in the engine bay on the other side of the engine - away from the filter. Also capture exhaust noise - you will need some wind mufflers to be able to achieve this.